# Check which user pushed to a docker image

Tags: docker

How I can know who (username) pushed the latest version to a docker image.

I tried `docker inspect` and `docker history`, but no luck.

Sorry if this question might sound very stupid, but I need to know whom to contact regarding a change, but I can't find it.

Comment: If the image does not contain a MAINTAINER you are pretty much out of luck. And even if the MAINTAINER is there, it does not need to be correct.